# aggregate per tags, when each rows has an array of tags

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have a dataframe with a column holding an array of tags. I would like to know the sum of the column `val` for each tag `a` (11),`b` (5),`c` (15),`d` (16). What's the best way to achieve this on the following dataframe?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["val", "tags"], \
                  data=[ [5,["a","b","c"]], [6,["a","d"]], [10,["c","d"]]])
```

Is there a better way than the approach of this pseudo-code?

```
acc = {}
for row in df:
  for tag in row.tags
    if tag in acc:
      acc[tag]+=row.val
    else
      acc[tag]=val
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So first flatten your list column , using `repeat` and dataframe constructor , then do `groupby` + `sum`

```
pd.DataFrame({'val':df.val.repeat(df.tags.str.len()),'tags':sum(df.tags,[])}).groupby('tags').sum()
Out[97]: 
      val
tags     
a      11
b       5
c      15
d      16
```

Comment: `df.tags.map(len)` rather than `df.tags.str.len()`seems to work and might be more intuitive (I didn't understand how string functions could be used here as it is an array it works on, but I guess it's just making sure the function `len` is called, without checking on what data it is working on).